# How to access all Harddrives in kivy FileChooser Python

Tags: python, kivy, filechooser

how can I display all harddrives installed in the System (C,X,J) in a kivy FileChooser using either Listview or Iconview in kivy 1.11.1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I faced the same problem and finally solved it by adding "shortcut" buttons for the drives. I start by getting a list of all the drives using:

```
drives = ['%s:' % d for d in string.ascii_uppercase if os.path.exists('%s:' % d)]
```

Then creating a `Button` for each drive, with the `on_release` bound to an `open_entry()` method. The `open_entry()` method creates a fake `Entry` and calls the `FileChooser` `open_entry()` method.

Comment: Good solution/work around! Using Kivy 2.0.0 and all other solutions on stack use deprecated functions such as `listadapters` and `listviews`.

Answer (score 3):

The best solution I found is Kivy's Garden FileBrowser widget:

https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.filebrowser

Which produces the following layout:

[image]